# How does cin.clear() clear the input buffer?

Tags: c++, io, cin

From what I have read, `cin.clear()` resets the flags, but how does this clear the input buffer?

Comment: I think the think that flushes the input buffer is`cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`. However It is used with `cin.clear()` to completely reset cin.

Answer (score 3):

`cin.clear()` has no effect on the input buffer. As you correctly read, it resets the `iostate` flags (technically, replaces their current value with `std::ios_base::goodbit`)

Comment: Can you explain, why getline() skipped after `cin >> variable` ? due to `\n' ?

Comment: @UnKnown it doesn't "skip", it does exactly what it's designed to do. See Notes section here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline#Notes

Comment: mean it's designed to read string until it fined '\n' and because it find '\n' by last `Enter Pressed` that's why it executed/skipped?

Answer (score 2):

`std::ios::clear()` only resets the error flags, if possible. If there is, e.g., no stream buffer (i.e., `stream.rdbuf()` yield `nullptr`) the `std::ios_base::badbit` still stays set. That is the only affect. In particular, `std::ios_base::clear()` does not remove any characters from an input buffer.

If you need to remove character from the input buffer, you'll need to do it explicitly. For example you can use

- `stream.ignore();` to unconditionally remove the next character (if any; if there is none, the stream will get `std::ios_base::eofbit` set).
- `stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to remove all character up to and including the first `'\n'` character encountered.
- you might want to `ignore()` characters while `stream.peek()` yields a character class you don't like (e.g., while `isdigit(stream.peek())` yields `false`)

Comment: Why getline() skipped here? `std::cin >> k;
    getline(std::cin,a);` where k is an integer..!! i know it could be fixed by using `cin.ignore();` but what is the reason behind failure?

Comment: @Unknown: this exact question is asked and answered plenty of times before (I know because I have answered it multiple times): please learn how to search Stackoverflow!

Comment: sorry I forget to add that. if k is integer then still `\n` caused the problem?

Comment: @Unknown: look for an answer to the question, understand it, and yiu'll be able to answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

cin.clear() doesn't clear the buffer, it only overwrites the current values of the flag.
For more details you can visit this link-->
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

And You can find a good example in this link-->http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/classes/cs102/Cin-Notes/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `cin.clear()` has no effect on the input buffer it only sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags.

If you want to clear the characters that "broke" your stream, you must use `cin.ignore()` (e.g., `cin.ignore(10000,'\n');`)

You can find a nice explanation with intuitive examples here: http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student1.html