# Proper way to flush cin input

Tags: c++, input, whitespace, cin, getline

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a, b, c, d;

void main()
{
    cout << "Reading a" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
//  cin.clear();
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Reading b" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
//  cin.clear();
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Reading c" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
//  cin.clear();
    cin >> c;

    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I read 3 times to variables from a to c. It works when fine when I enter random number then accept it using no white spaces (`23` , `45` , `66`). However when my input looks like this `23 45 66` (spaces in between), it immediately puts `23` to `a`, `45` to `b` and `66` to `c`.

My intention is to read number, end on whitespace, then forget the rest of the input and read again to the next variable.

`cin.ignore()` and `cin.clear()` don't seem to help me, but probably I am using them wrong.

I could make my own buffer and then check it for whitespaces, but before doing that I want to see if there is another way.

Comment: Read a whole line with getline then perform string to integer conversion using stoi

Comment: Works great and it's very quick to implement. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered by mikedu95 in a comment:

> Read a whole line with `getline`, then perform string to integer conversion using `stoi`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string str;
int a, b, c, d;

void main()
{
    cout << "Reading a" << endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    a = stoi(str);

    cout << "Reading b" << endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    b = stoi(str);

    cout << "Reading c" << endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    c = stoi(str);

    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find your answer here:
[How does cin.clear() clear the input buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832289/how-does-cin-clear-clear-the-input-buffer)

I bring here part of an answer from this page:

If you need to remove character from the input buffer, you'll need to do it explicitly. For example you can use

- `stream.ignore();` to unconditionally remove the next character (if any; if there is none, the stream will get `std::ios_base::eofbit` set).
- `stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to remove all character up to and including the first `'\n'` character encountered.
- you might want to `ignore()` characters while `stream.peek()` yields a character class you don't like (e.g., while `isdigit(stream.peek())` yields `false`)